# Heterogeneous node types and edge types with boost::graph

Tags: templates, c++11, graph, containers, boost-graph

Is it possible to have multiple node types and also multiple edge types (node to edge type map) by using the boost::graph library?

( This question is related to the following code review: [code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/82308/efficient-compile-time-directed-graph) )

Answer (score 1):

Answering your code review question here:

Your graph is not completely compile-time.

Regardless of the underlying structure "graph", think about functions like `vertex v =  add_vertex(graph)`. You can probably overload with code like 
`traits<DataType>::vertex v = add_vertex(graph, data)` where add_vertex is a template.

For corresponding function `add_edge(s,t, graph, data);` you will need much more complicated overloading.

Compiler has no ways to envision which vertices will be added. It means some type of run-time dispatch is unavoidable. It can be virtual-table polymorphism, or Boost.Variant, or flag-based naive variant, or even double-dispatch (aka Visitor pattern).

Comment: I think you are right, the graph can never have only compile time dispatching, because if you look at the storage types which is needed inside a `Node` is always heterogenous, which fills the need for some variant (like in boost:variant), vtable polymorphism, etc... but there is always a runtime cast branch, however I think a separate special implementation instead of boost::graph is preferable since we can store the different vertex types in **separate storages** ( e.g : `std::tuple< std::vector<VertexType1> , std::vector<VertexType2> ... >` ) , which makes applying visitors faster!! ?

Comment: with your implementation, one needs to visit (run-time branch with cast) each vertext (boost::variant)  in the visitation loop over the nodes for example, which is slow

Comment: Storing separate types in separate storages is possible. You can have a custom structure to keep vertices and edges. In such case some operations (like add_edge) will be faster. However, the _traversal_ will become a nightmare. Your iterators will become "boost::variants". All Boost graph functions like  "get_edges(v,g)" will return variants, etc.

Answer (score 1):

In theory you can have a graph where vertex type is a Boost.Variant of several types. Similarly you can also make the edge type a Boost.Variant.

However, if you want the fastest traversal possible I would recommend to keep vertex and edge types simple. Instead, you can use Boost.Variant for edge and vertex (bundled) *properties*.